# How to know the exact location of the gcc installation

Tags: linux, gcc, redhat

first i used command : **which gcc**

If it shows location other than /usr/bin, then how to set the right path to compile the C program

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon your [$PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29). And that could be set to something starting with a directory containing some `gcc` command. Run `echo $PATH` to find out what is your current `$PATH`.

You could either type exactly `/usr/bin/gcc`, or add some `alias` to your interactive shell configuration (often `~/.bashrc` which you might *edit* with great *care*), or change your `PATH` setting, or, assuming `which gcc` gives something like `/home/zaid/bin/gcc` (i.e. your `$HOME/bin/gcc` if `$HOME/bin` appears *early* in your `$PATH`), add a symbolic link `ln -sv /usr/bin/gcc $HOME/bin/`.

If you compile a program made of *several* [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29), you should use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool, probably [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). Try once `make -p` to understand the builtin rules known to your `make` and take advantage of these. Then, edit your `Makefile`, perhaps by adding near its beginning lines like

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc
CFLAGS+= -Wall -g
```

The first line (with `CC=`) sets your C compiler in your `Makefile`. The second one (with `CFLAGS+=`) asks for all warnings (`-Wall`) & debug info (`-g`). Because you'll use the `gdb` debugger.